# Change format for specific fields in Nlog

Tags: nlog

For various reasons I'd like to output the processId in hexadecimal rather than in the default  decimal format when outputing logs from NLog.

I'm using `${processid}` in the layout, which outputs it in decimal. I know one can format dates using the format attribute, like `${shortdate:format=YYYY-mm-dd}`. Is there anything similar for ints?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything that will do that out of the box with NLog, but you could pretty easily write a LayoutRendererWrapper to do this.  In your NLog.config file, you would wrap the field you want convert, something like this:

```
${hex:inner=${processid}}
```

Here is a blog posting describing the feature:

http://nlog-project.org/2008/11/22/wrapper-layout-renderers-are-coming-to-nlog.html

You can find the source for all of the delivered LayoutRendererWrappers here:

https://github.com/jkowalski/NLog/tree/master/src/NLog/LayoutRenderers/Wrappers

The wrapper might look something like this (uncompiled and untested):

```
[LayoutRenderer("hex")]
[ThreadAgnostic]    
public sealed class HexLayoutRendererWrapper : WrapperLayoutRendererBase
{
  public HexLayoutRendererWrapper()
  {
    this.Culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
  }
  public CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }

  protected override string Transform(string text)        
  {
    int x;
    if (Int32.TryParse(text, out x))
    {
      string hex = string.Format("{0:X}", x);
      return hex;
    }
    else
    {
      return text;        
    }
  }    
}
```

You could even generalize and make a "formatting" wrapper that has a Format property that is then applied to the value before writing.